# fields_for missing when trying to add accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Im working on a simple form feature which adds an image via nested form.

Photo model which should store all of my uploaded images.

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :posting

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { large: "500x500>", medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100#" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

snippet of my nested form (within a form)

```
<%= post.fields_for :photos, html: { multipart: true } do |photo| %>
            <%= photo.label :image %>
            <%= photo.file_field :image %>
        <% end %>
```

Everything shows fine, but when I uncomment the accepts_nested_attributes_for line. My nested form disappears!

```
class Posting < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :subcategory
    belongs_to :category

    has_many :photos

    #accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you assigned a @post instance variable in your PostsController's new action. You have to add the build_photo method to the new action:

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
  @post.build_photo
end
```

This should show your nested form, too.

Comment: Thanks! I used  `@post.posting.build` instead, and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

See the *One-to-many* example in the API docs of [fields_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for)

Untested, but this should be your solution.

```
<% post.photos.each do |photo| %>
 <%= post.fields_for :photos, photo, html: { multipart: true } do |photo_fields| %>
   <%= photo_fields.label :image %>
   <%= photo_fields.file_field :image %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I think this should work, just missing a comma in the args list after `photo`

Comment: well spotted @FredWillmore. I added it.